# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable Class initialize

Tags: python

I want to create 2 classes in python one is card and deck of cards ,Here's a part
of the card class code:

```
class Card(object):
def __init__(self,Value,Type):
    self.Value=Value
    self.Type=Type
def PrintCard(self):
    print "<"+str(self.Value)+","+str(self.Type)+">"
def CardToString(self):
    return "<"+str(self.Value)+","+str(self.Type)+">"
```

Now here is the part of the deck class:

```
class Deck(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.Cards=[]
    self.NumOfCards=0
def FillDeck(self):
    self.Cards=[]
    self.NumOfCards=52
    for i in range(1,5):
        for j in range(2,15):
            TempCard=Card(j,i)
            self.Cards.append(TempCard)
def AddCard(self,OtherCard):
    self.Cards.append(OtherCard)
    self.NumOfCards=self.NumOfCards+1
def RemoveCard(self):
    if self.NumOfCards>=1:
        TempCard=self.Cards[0]
        self.Cards=self.Cards[1:]
        self.NumOfCards=self.NumOfCards-1
    else:
        return None
    return TempCard
def Count(self):
    return self.NumOfCards
```

now the error occurs when I press first for mission 2 and then try to add a card (mission3) :

```
symbol=["diamond","spade","club","heart"]
if TaskMission==2:
    if deck.Count()>0:
        Card=deck.RemoveCard()
        Card.PrintCard()
#Do Mission3
if TaskMission==3:
    flag=False
    x=raw_input()
    x=str.split(x)
    yolo=str(x[0]).isdigit()
    for i in range(5):
        if symbol[i]==x[1]:
            flag=i+1
            break
    if flag!=False and yolo==True:
        card=Card(int(abs(int(x[0]))),symbol[flag-1])
        deck.AddCard(card)
```

now the error is in the line :`card=Card(int(abs(int(x[0]))),symbol[flag-1])`

Comment: Your class code is not indented properly. Does it match your code? It also looks like you shadowed Card. Use capital letter on class declaration, lowercase for an instance. The same applies to your attributes. Check out **pep8** for details on naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Card=deck.RemoveCard()
    Card.PrintCard()
```

Once this code executes, the class `Card` is no longer accessible; its value has been overshadowed. Later, when you do `Card(int(abs(...))`, Card refers to whatever `RemoveCard()` returned, rather than the `Card` class.

Change the name of your variable to something else so this collision does not occur.

```
    thing=deck.RemoveCard()
    thing.PrintCard()
```

Comment: The second example should probably be `card.PrintCard` right?

Comment: sure, it can be `card.PrintCard()`, as long as you do `card=deck.RemoveCard()` on the previous line.